# Samesite=Strict behavior after oidc login

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, samesite, duende-identity-server

I am running a **Client Application** and **Identity Server** on localhost on different ports with `http:` and Identity Server has external login provider hosted on `https:`

I have configured Auth Server to set Correlation and Nonce cookies to be SameSite=Strict:

```
        options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
```

Also Client Application to set SameSite=Strict

```
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict
        });
```

This is the request chain:

- requesting the home page :

  `GET http://localhost:5001 => Reponse: 302`
- redirecting to auth provider :

  `GET http://localhost:5000/Challenge?returnUrl='' => Returns 302`
- Redirection to external auth provider and callback :

  `GET https://externalauth.com/authorize`

  `GET https://externalauth.com/callback`
- Rediect to handle auth callback :

  **`GET http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc => Returns 404`**

Now My question is as below:

- According to this documentation https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identityserver/samesite-cookies-in-a-nutshell/ of SameSite=Strict cookies are sent when [image]
  **So is this considered 1st party request** ? because I have already hit the browser with http://localhost:5001. What else could be the reason for cookies not being sent ?
- Cookies are being set in the browser as below but not sent with the request. They are sent only when I use Samesite=Lax. What cloud be the possible reason ?
  [image]

Comment: The cookies from IdentityServer needs to have samesite=none;secure, to work. otherwise they will not be included in cross domain requests.

Comment: @ToreNestenius, Even if client & identity server both are on same domain(localhost) ?

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS on the same domain is still separate sites. (different scheme)

Comment: @ToreNestenius, Indeed, different schemes but I haven't set them to be secure(added picture in the question). Hence They should be considered same site.

Comment: Strict cookies will never be included in request cross site, you need to use none for that.

Comment: But as per the documentation, I consider my request same site as it is localhost with same scheme(http) just different port.

Comment: Different ports are also different sites.

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thanks, Any heads up for reference /documentation ?

Comment: Start here https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/08/changes-to-samesite-cookie-behavior/

I will post my answer as a real answer here, hope you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The cookies from IdentityServer needs to have samesite=none;secure, to work. otherwise they will not be included in cross domain requests.

When you have a cookie with samesite=strict for a site like https://localhost:5001, then that means that the cookie will not be included to requests to:

```
http://localhost:5001   (Different scheme)
https://localhost:5002  (Different port)
```

This is a good starting point about samesite cookies.
[Changes to SameSite Cookie Behavior – A Call to Action for Web Developers](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/08/changes-to-samesite-cookie-behavior/)

To get a cookie to behave as before, then you need to mark it with samesite=none;secure. And you must use HTTPS.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: "The cookies from IdentityServer needs to have samesite=none;secure, to work. otherwise they will not be included in cross domain requests." Could you share the source for this?

Comment: You can verify that yourself by setting the samesite flag to some other value. The browser will then tell you that they are either blocked or rejected. See my blog post here:  https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/    Samesite must be set on all cookies for optimal compatibilty.  The main problem is the redirect back from IdentityServer to your application. that is a cross site request and some browsers will block that.